# passwords.google.com doesn't load passwords

Tags: google-account, google-chrome, passwords, google-smart-lock

It is about 2 weeks that https://passwords.google.com/ doesn't load my passwords.
After logging in to https://passwords.google.com/ I'm stuck with "Loading…".

I first tried to flush cache, reset browser settings and navigate using incognito mode. Then I tried several browsers, computers and internet connections. But nothing changed. I get always the same problem.

I think it is related to my Google account, but no one knows what causes this.
Here is a [discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/iLgCUiUfUU8) about this glitch, but even there no one knows how to solve it.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using `https`?

Comment: Yes, even i do not use it Google automatically redirects to `https`

Comment: Loads for me. Have you tried a different network? A different browser? I suspect that something between you and the site is blocking it. Can you do a traceroute to `passwords.google.com`?

Comment: Yes, as i said in my post, i tried different networks, computers and obviously browsers. I know that it loads for you, as i said it seems to be a problem related to certain Google accounts.

Comment: Ah, yes, so you did. _Mea culpa_. I'm afraid I don't have anything else useful to suggest.

Comment: Is this a consumer @ gmail.com account?  If this account was supplied by your work, school, or another organization then the Admins of this group may have disabled or turned off this service. If that's the case you would need to follow up with them. If this is a @ gmail.com account the only other step I can recommend is creating a new account, and confirming this brand new test account doesn't have the same issue. This will just help confirm if the issue is related to the account or not.

Comment: Yes, it is a consumer gmail account. Thank you anyway for your reply.

Comment: This question is about a service for chrome, chromebook and android users. As the question is specific about chrome, it should be moved to [su].

Comment: @Rubén This question is about the website https://passwords.google.com/ which is usable from any browser. Just because it accesses the same password store which is deeply integrated with Android and Chrome and only lets you retrieve or delete passwords does not mean it isn’t a website usable by itself.

Comment: @binki: I just mean that this question isn't on topic on this site. Troubleshooting is off-topic. If you would like to discuss more about what is on-topic/off-topic on this site, consider to post a question on [meta].

Comment: @Rubén Maybe the correct answer for a question like this is “here’s how to actually contact Google about this problem” or something. Figuring out what to do when encountering unexpected behavior in a webapp seems to me to be consistent with [“Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application”](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @binki: The question already include a link to a thread on the Google Products Help Forum, so I think that the OP already know about how Google handles the support for consumers. As I previously said, on this site troubleshooting is off-topic. Take a look to this thread on [meta] -> https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3799/88163

Comment: fyi, this is also happening to me in June 2018 for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Google Product Forums thread referenced by the asker](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/iLgCUiUfUU8), this was a bug that Google eventually fixed sometime before 2016-03-16.

Unfortunately, for this sort of question where there is really no action that the user can take to resolve the issue, the best course of action is to report the issue to Google. Google’s main support article for the passwords feature, “[Manage saved passwords from the web](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6208650)”, suggests that https://passwords.google.com/ is considered a part of Chrome:

> If you use Chrome sync, or [Google Smart Lock for Passwords on Android](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6197437), you can view the passwords you’ve saved in Chrome and Android on any browser by visiting [passwords.google.com](https://passwords.google.com/).

Google’s [instructions for reporting problems with Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315) suggest to use *Help* -> *Report and issue* from the menu inside Chrome itself. And, as you already discovered, a place to look for other users with the same issue is the [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/chrome)

Answer (score -4):

Try to delete "Google Chrome" and re-download it on your laptop or PC, it should work fine.